# LinkToken with account filters - credit/credit card - not working

Tags: plaid

We have the following code to retrieve only credit card accounts from an institution:

```
    LinkTokenCreateRequest.User user = new LinkTokenCreateRequest.User(person.getUuid().toString());
    Map<String, LinkTokenCreateRequest.SubtypeFilters> accountFilters = new HashMap<>();
    accountFilters.put("credit", new LinkTokenCreateRequest.SubtypeFilters(Collections.singletonList("credit card")));

    LinkTokenCreateRequest request = new LinkTokenCreateRequest
            (user, clientName, Collections.singletonList("auth"), Collections.singletonList("US"), "en")
            .withAccountFilters(accountFilters);
```

When we try to get Link Token with the above code we get an error from Plaid:

```
errorCode: "INVALID_FIELD"
errorMessage: "account_filters must be nonempty Map<account type, Map<\"account_subtypes\", Array<account subtype>>> where account type and account subtype are strings. There must also be at least 1 valid product and account type combination."
errorType: "INVALID_REQUEST"
```

We are using plaid-java version 8.1.0

Without account filters, we can get all the accounts from an institution, but we want to only retrieve credit card accounts. The above code also works find with "depository"/"checking" filter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is because of an invalid product/account type combination; the Auth product is not compatible with credit cards. From the Auth docs at https://plaid.com/docs/auth/ "Auth can only be used with checking or savings accounts...Auth data cannot be used to set up credit card payments."

Comment: Thanks @alex! Which product and API should I use to get transactions of a credit card?  (Also, when I do connect to the institution, it actually returns all accounts - including credit card accounts - with Auth product. But it doesn't filter the accounts properly.)

Comment: using  product "transactions" fixed the filtering issue. But it looks like, when I do download transactions, its getting transactions from savings and checking accounts as well.. even though user has not selected.

Comment: Yes, that's currently expected behavior for non-OAuth institutions -- you can see which account the user selected based on the information provided in the Link callback, then filter to only use/display transactions from that account: https://plaid.com/docs/link/web/#link-web-onsuccess-accounts_metadata

Comment: Thanks @Alex! Appreciate the quick response.